# How to select items when scrolling on RecyclerView GridLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll

I've tried to achieve an interaction like the one on the Samsung calendar

[samsung calendar app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5G4Q.gif)

I understand that you have to work with the Touch Event (I saw it in the Android documentation) but I still can't get to do that interaction.

```
@Override
public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {                 
  view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
       return false;
     }
   });
}
```

Comment: Where have u set this callback? Can you please provide more code, at least the code surrounding the above and which class/view you are dealing with here? That can help us provide some help.

Comment: sorry, i add my code in bottom answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class RecyclerTouchListener implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
private ClickListener clickListener;

public RecyclerTouchListener(Context context, final RecyclerView recyclerView, final ClickListener clickListener) {
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
    gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onLongClick(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            View child = recyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
                clickListener.onDown(child, recyclerView.getChildPosition(child), e);
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
            return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null && gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)) {
        clickListener.onClick(child, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
    View child = rv.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
    if (child != null && clickListener != null) {
        clickListener.onTouchEvent(rv, e, rv.getChildPosition(child));
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) {

}

public interface ClickListener {
    void onClick(View view, int position);

    void onLongClick(View view, int position);

    void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e, int childPosition);

    void onDown(View view, int position, MotionEvent e);

}
```

}

it's my Listener I have implemented